# Erro ao gerar relatório com Jasper Reports usando JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jasper

Estou seguindo um [tutorial](https://pobrecomputeiro.wordpress.com/2010/08/14/jasperreports-para-quem-tem-jsf-2-e-o-primefaces/) que explica como gerar relatórios com `iReport` usando `JSF`. Montei meu relatório no iReport e ele está funcionando perfeitamente, ou seja quando dou um *preview* todos os dados do banco que selecionei são carregados no relatório. O problema começa quando tento gerar esse relatório:

Esse é o primeiro erro:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.getFormat(JRFillTextField.java:706)

Depois esse:

> GRAVE: Erro de sistema: null   javax.faces.FacesException    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:89)

E esse:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.primefaces.component.filedownload.FileDownloadActionListener.processAction(FileDownloadActionListener.java:81)

Método que gera o relatório:

```
public StreamedContent getSampleReportPDF(){

    InputStream relatorio = null;

    try {
        String pdfFile = "C:\\sampleReport.pdf";

        ByteArrayOutputStream Teste = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Report/RelatorioReembolso.jasper"));
        jasperReport.setWhenNoDataType(WhenNoDataTypeEnum.ALL_SECTIONS_NO_DETAIL);

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, ConexaoMysql.abrir());

        JRExporter exporter = new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter();

        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, pdfFile);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, Teste);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
        exporter.exportReport();

        relatorio = new ByteArrayInputStream(Teste.toByteArray());
    } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new DefaultStreamedContent(relatorio);

}
```

Botão que faz o download do relatório gerado:

```xml
<p:commandButton rendered="true" id="exportar" title="Exportar" ajax="false">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{listarReembolsoBean.sampleReportPDF}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido, estava usando uma versão muito antiga do `Jasper` alterei minha dependência pra essa versão:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Fiz algumas alterações no meu método que gera o relatório também, preferi fazer com que ele abra na tela do `Jasper` mesmo dessa maneira:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu método ficou dessa forma(Passo um código como parâmetro para retornar apenas a consulta referente ao objeto clicado na tabela e também passo uma imagem como parâmetro):

```
public void gerarRelatorio(Solicitacao rel) {
        Map<String, Object> filtro = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        System.out.println("Codigo solicitacao:" + rel.getCodigo());
        try {
            InputStream image = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Report/logo-unimed-correto.png");
            filtro.put("codigo", rel.getCodigo());
            filtro.put("image", image);

            JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader
                    .loadObject(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Report/RelatorioReembolso.jasper"));
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, filtro, ConexaoMysql.abrir());
            JasperViewer jrviewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
            jrviewer.setVisible(true);
            jrviewer.toFront();
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgInfo("Relatório Gerando com Sucesso!!");
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao gerar relatório: "+ex.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao gerar relatório: "+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

E o meu `commandButton` que fica dentro de uma `dataTable` ficou assim:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-print"
        title="Exportar Relatório"
        actionListener="#{listarReembolsoBean.gerarRelatorio(reembolso)}"
        update=":frmPrin :msgGlobal">
</p:commandButton>
```